# Getting errno after an error in wrapped c function in Python

Tags: python, ctypes, errno

I'm learning how to wrap c functions using Python's `ctypes' and am able to wrap and call a function, but I can't figure out how to get the`errno` after there is an error. For this example, I'm wrapping [inotify_add_watch](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/inotify_add_watch.2.html). This isn't the full code, just an example of something that will cause an error:

```
import ctypes

c_lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')

inotify_add = c_lib.inotify_add_watch
inotify_add.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_uint32)
inotify_add.restype = ctypes.c_int

# This will cause an EBADF error
inotify_add(32, b'/tmp', 1)  # returns -1
```

And the documentation I linked says this will return `-1` which it does, but that it also will set `errno` appropriately. I cannot figure out how to access `errno` now. If I try `ctypes.get_errno()`, this just returns `0`. If I try to call `c_lib.errno()`, this causes a `segmentation error`, so that isn't working either. Is there a way I can retrieve `errno`?

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50669907/how-to-use-ctypes-errcheck/50675541#50675541

Comment: I've looked at that and have my `errcheck` functions working correctly. They will see the problem and raise an error if the result is `-1`. The problem is that I cannot find the actual error that would be set my `errno`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get errno from the same CRT library that Python was built with.  So for Python 3.7 on Windows.  I don't have Linux handy to try, so hopefully this puts you in the right direction.

```
>>> dll = CDLL('ucrtbase',use_errno=True)
>>> get_errno()
0
>>> dll._access(b'nonexisting',0)
-1
>>> get_errno()
2
```

Errno 2 is ENOENT (No such file or directory) so it got set and looks correct.

A different CRT library has a different `errno` instance so it isn't captured correctly by Python for use with `set_errno()/get_errno()`.