# Issue with "map" function between python 2 and 3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, ctypes, converters

I am using a code written by someone else to read and encode data from a converter digital/analogic. I try to improve this code by making it working with python 3 since it was encode in python 2.

I have reduced the code a lot to understand why it does not work on Python 3 and found an issue with the "map" function behavior since it says that an "Error occured in  in Python 3, but not in python 2.

I do not know where I am doing wrong since, as I have not made this code myself, there are some parts that I cannot understand. 
What should I change to make it working with python 3?

---

```
from DTOL import DTOL

io = DTOL(name='DT9818(00)')

io.Initialize('DT9818(00)')
io.setupGetSingleValue()
```

---

DTOL

---

```
import ctypes
from time import sleep
from DTOL_defs import *
from DTOL_prototypes import *

class DTOL:
    """ Data Translation DtOLWrapper Class """
    def __init__(self, name='DT9818(00)'):
        self.name = name
        self.data = []
        self.sshandle = []
        self.hdev = []
        self.range = (-10,10)
        self.rmin = ctypes.c_double(-10)
        self.rmax = ctypes.c_double(10)
        self.gain = ctypes.c_double(1)
        self.res = ctypes.c_uint(16)
        self.enc = ctypes.c_uint(OL_ENC_BINARY)
        self.val = 0

    def Initialize(self, name):
        print('Available Boards:')
        olDaEnumBoards(listboardscallback, 1)
        print('-----')
        print('Initializing: ' + str(name))
        name = name.encode('utf-8')
        hdev = olDaInitialize(name)
        self.hdev = hdev
        return hdev

    def GetSubsystem(self, subsystem_code, elemNum):
        print(subsystem_code)
        print(elemNum)
        sshandle = olDaGetDASS(self.hdev, subsystem_code, elemNum)
        self.sshandle = sshandle
        return sshandle

    def setupGetSingleValue(self):
        self.Initialize(self.name)
        self.GetSubsystem(OLSS_AD, ctypes.c_ulong(0))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Usage: io=DTOL('DT9818(00)')")
    print("io.setupSingleValue()")
    print("io.getSingleValue()")
    io = DTOL()
    io.setupGetSingleValue()
```

---

DTOL_prototypes

---

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.util import find_library

dll = ctypes.CDLL(find_library('oldaapi64'))
dll2 = ctypes.CDLL(find_library('OLMEM64'))

def errcheck_all(ret, func, args):
    if ret:
        print("Error occured in"+ str(func))
        return

    return args

def errcheck_none(ret, func, args):
    if ret:
        print("Error occured in"+ str(func))
        print(ret)
        return

# ----------- Initialize ---------------------------------
prototype = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong))
paramflags = (1, "name"), (2,"hDev")
olDaInitialize = prototype(('olDaInitialize', dll), paramflags)
olDaInitialize.errcheck = errcheck_all
# -----------END Initialize ---------------------------------

# ----------- olDaGetDASS ---------------------------------
prototype = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong))
paramflags = (1, "hDev"), (1,"SubsystemType"), (1,"uiElementNr"), (2,"adhandle")
olDaGetDASS = prototype(('olDaGetDASS',dll), paramflags)
olDaGetDASS.errcheck = errcheck_all
# ----------- olDaGetDASS ---------------------------------
```

---

DTOL_defs

---

```
import ctypes

(OLSS_AD, 
OLSS_DA, 
OLSS_DIN, 
OLSS_DOUT, 
OLSS_SRL, 
OLSS_CT) = list(map(ctypes.c_int, (range(6))))

OL_ENC_BINARY = 200
```

---

As a result, I found this difference between python 3 and 2:
Python 3:

```
c_long(0)
<class 'ctypes.c_long'>
Available Boards:
Name = b'DT9818(00)'
Drivername = b'Dt9818'
1
-----
Initializing: DT9818(00)
Available Boards:
Name = b'DT9818(00)'
Drivername = b'Dt9818'
1
-----
Initializing: DT9818(00)
c_long(0)
c_ulong(0)
Error occured in<WinFunctionType object at 0x00000235269DC528>
```

Python 2:

```
c_long(0)
<class 'ctypes.c_long'>
Available Boards:
Name = DT9818(00)
Drivername = Dt9818
1
-----
Initializing: DT9818(00)
Available Boards:
Name = DT9818(00)
Drivername = Dt9818
1
-----
Initializing: DT9818(00)
c_long(0)
c_ulong(0L)
```

The two last parameters correspond to "print(subsystem_code)" and "print(elemNum)" respectively.

Comment: always show full `Traceback` in question.

Comment: What do you mean by traceback?

Comment: when you get error message then it starts with word `Traceback`. People put only last line of error (error message) but all text can be important.

Comment: In python 3 I got:
    Available Boards:
    Name = b'DT9818(00)'
    Drivername = b'Dt9818'
    1
    -----
    Initializing: DT9818(00)
    Available Boards:
    Name = b'DT9818(00)'
    Drivername = b'Dt9818'
    1
    -----
    Initializing: DT9818(00)
    c_long(0)
    c_ulong(0)
    Error occured in<WinFunctionType object at 0x00000235269DC528>

In python 2, I got different type for the second:
    c_long(0)
    c_ulong(0L) (This one correspond to:
print (OLSS_AD)
print(type(OLSS_AD)) respectively

Comment: I did not say, but I did not get traceback since I removed most of the code in order to identify where the problem came from.

Comment: put this in question - it will be more readable and everyone will see it. Not everyone read comments.

Comment: Thank you , I have made it in the question

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you think that *map* would be the problem. The way it's called (constructing a *list* out of it) works identically on both *Python* versions.

Posting [[Python 3]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

I can't be *100%* sure without the functions documentation, but from the way they're declared:

1. *olDaInitialize*:

   ```py
   prototype = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong))
   paramflags = (1, "name"), (2, "hDev")
   ```
2. *olDaGetDASS*:

   ```py
   prototype = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong))
   paramflags = (1, "hDev"), (1, "SubsystemType"), (1, "uiElementNr"), (2, "adhandle")
   ```

I can conclude that **return values represent the functions execution statuses**, typically:

- ***0*** for success
- Any other *int* value representing an error code

But, in *Initialize*, you set *hDev* (which is output for *olDaInitialize* and input for *olDaGetDASS*) like this (there's also a type mismatch, but it's hidden by automatic casting):

```py
hdev = olDaInitialize(name)
self.hdev = hdev
```

so you assign to *hdev* the status of *olDaInitialize* which makes no sense. The proper way to do this would be:

- In *__init__*:

  ```py
  self.hdev = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
  ```
- In *Initialize*:

  ```py
  hdev = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
  status = olDaInitialize(name, ctypes.byref(hdev))
  if status == 0:  # Or whichever value means SUCCESS
      self.hdev = hdev
  ```

The **exact same thing also applies to *adhandle*** (*olDaGetDASS*'s last argument), which you reference in *GetSubsystem* (as *sshandle*) and probably use someplace else in the code.

While we are at *improvements* section:

- The *name* being passed to both *__init__* and *Initialize* seems redundant. I'd suggest to leave it in the initializer, and in the body do:

  ```py
  self.name = name.encode("utf-8")
  ```

  and then remove the argument from *Initialize*, and use `self.name` inside it
- You are using *errcheck* functionality, but right now it's not helping at all. You could improve that (e.g. by also displaying the error code). More details on [[SO]: How to use ctypes' errcheck? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50669907/how-to-use-ctypes-errcheck/50675541#50675541)
- *Initialize* is called twice: in the main script and in *setupGetSingleValue*. You should **remove the call from one place** (I'd say the latter)
- *olDaEnumBoards* (and *listboardscallback*) are missing. Also, where are the **1<sup>st</sup> 2 lines** printed from?
- Try keeping your identifier names consistent ([[Python]: PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008))

***@EDIT0***:

Adding some simplified code, to check whether problem reproduces.

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import ctypes


def main():
    oldaapi64 = ctypes.CDLL(find_library("oldaapi64"))
    olmem64 = ctypes.CDLL(find_library("olmem64"))

    oldainitialize = oldaapi64.olDaInitialize
    oldainitialize.argtypes = [
        ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong),
    ]
    oldainitialize.restype = ctypes.c_int

    oldagetdass = olmem64.olDaGetDASS
    oldagetdass.argtypes = [
        ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong),
    ]
    oldagetdass.restype = ctypes.c_int

    dev = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    res = oldainitialize(b"DT9818(00)", ctypes.byref(dev))
    print("{:s} returned {:d}. Dev: {:d}".format(oldainitialize.name, res, dev.value))

    OLSS_AD = 0
    element_num = 0
    handle = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    res = oldagetdass(dev, OLSS_AD, element_num, ctypes.byref(handle))
    print("{:s} returned {:d}. Handle: {:d}".format(oldagetdass.name, res, handle.value))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("Done.")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. I have followed what you said, but it seems that I obtain exactly the same thing.. The thing is that I have not encode this as I said, and I have some difficulties to understand the logic under it since I am not a programmer.. 
In any case, thank you very much once more.

Comment: Did you also modified *GetSubsystem* (declaring `self.sshandle = ctypes.c_ulong(0)`, and then passing it to *olDaGetDASS* as the last argument)?

Comment: Indeed, I did it also, but I still get the win error and the type is still c_ulong(0) rather than c_ulong(0L)

Comment: Hmm, that's strange .And both *Python* versions are *64bit*? I could prepare a small piece of code that only calls the functions, no structure at all for you to try, if you'd like.

Comment: Could you also add in the question *C* prototypes for the 2 functions?

Comment: Indeed, both are in 64bit and on the same computer. Therefore, all other files are the same. 
What do you mean by C prototypes for 2 functions? 
If you have a small piece of code, I would really appreciate. Thank you in advance

Comment: How do *olDaInitialize* and *olDaGetDASS* look like in *C*? I mean how did you created their `prototype = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(.....` (based on what)? they should be in a *.h* file, something like: `int olDaInitialize(int name, ....`.

Comment: As I mentioned, I have not made this program that works perfectly on python 2.7... therefore, I am still struggling for understanding some parts..